# How to wait for more data in libuv?

Tags: libuv

I am testing on libuv for server.

The problem is that the data is to arrive partially and I need to wait for more data. 
(this situation hasn't occurred yet but I think it is around the corner, in my experience)

But this libuv is dependent on event base, and next after_read() function
doesn't guarantee the next packet would be the leftover.

I wonder how you work around. 
Thank you.

---

Added for more information.
My concerned situation of splitted packet.

- Assume Client A, Client B, Server S.

  1. A sends 100 bytes to server.
  2. B sends 100 bytes to server.
  3. S receives A's first 50 bytes. (in read callback)
  4. S receives B's 100 bytes. (in read callback)
  5. S receives A's rest 50 bytes. (in read callback)

After step 3, I expect the rest A's 50bytes to arrive , but unlike my expectation, B's 100 bytes arrive.  my goal is to merge step 3 (50bytes) + step 5 (50bytes) for A's entire data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In libuv you don't wait for data, you request that data is read by calling `uv_read_start` and then the read callback will be called when there is data to read. If your application needs to read complete packets of data, you typically want to use a state machine to know what state you're in, and keep buffering data until you have a full packet.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, saghul. I know about the basic feature of uv_read_start and callback function. But I am concerned about splitted packet. I added more explanation on my posting. Do I need to manage all the packet or is there any good way to deal with the packet order and fragment?

Comment: I don't think you can handle this without a state machine and some buffering. For each connection you buffer 1 packet, and avoid processing until it's complete. If you are using UDP, you'd need a mapping between the source address and the packet buffer, thus complicating things. libuv has no builtin facility to help you here since this is very application specific.

Comment: Yes. I also think it's application specific, but I asked for fear of my ignorance. I am considering on allocating specific size buffer per each client at this very moment. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If your packet size is fixed, then you can allocate space for the full packet in on_alloc, and then pass a pointer to the remaining buffer on subsequent calls until the packet is complete.

Comment: my packet is dynamic, but has a packet marker at first byte and lenth at next byte. so I can find the entire length beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

To handle this simply create your own derived tcp type with whatever connection specific information you need.

```
typedef struct
{
  uv_tcp_t base;
  int idx;
} my_tcp_t;
```

Then malloc your struct and cast it

```
my_tcp_t *client = (my_tcp_t*) malloc(sizeof(my_tcp_t));
client->idx = 2;
uv_tcp_init(loop, (uv_tcp_t*)client);
```

The idx variable is available in the read callback by casting back (my_tcp_t*).

Comment: Much time's passed since my last reply. I will consider on yours when I work on libuv again next time.  maybe back in that project, it seems like I implemented similar to yours. Thank you.